# Google Identity Platform pricing - Monthly Active User

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-identity

I'm trying to pin pricing on a use case for Identity Platform and would appreciate if anyone can confirm how the pricing works.

[The pricing documentation](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/pricing) states:

> Any account that has signed in within a given month is considered an active user. Inactive users are stored at no cost.

My reading of this is that I could create a user account programmatically (e.g. in a cloud function) and I would not be charged for that account, until and unless someone actually signs in to that account. (As opposed to the user being counted as active for the month in which the account is created, login or no.) Does anyone know if that reading is correct?

Comment: When you need to split hairs over the wording of a statement/policy, you need to go to the authority, which is Google Cloud Billing. Open a support ticket. You are asking for an opinion which is off-topic here. https://cloud.google.com/support/billing

Answer (score 0):

According to this [identity platform pricing model](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/pricing#:%7E:text=Any%20account%20that%20has%20signed,are%20charged%20per%20successful%20verification.) document:

Identity Platform charges per Monthly Active User (MAU) for most sign-in methods.

That is, any account that has signed in within a given month is considered an active user. Inactive users are stored at no cost.

Phone and multi-factor authentication users are charged per successful verification.